# How to know if a view is visible or not when other view is over it?

Tags: android, layout, view

### How could I programmatically know on an Android app if the icon is visible or not according to the transparency of the view over it?

See that this is not a trivial question. I want to know if the icon is visible by the naked eye on its totality, independently of the complexity of the view over it.

[image: Two devices shows a view over an icon. In the first one the icon is not visible, because the view over it has a solid color. In the second one, the icon is visible, since the view over it is transparent.]

Answer (score -1):

For kotlin use `if((yourView).visibility == View.VISIBLE)`.

then check alpha of the view that is overlapping your view if it is more than a certain threshold yourView is visible otherwise it just cannot be considered visible.

Comment: The icon behind could have the visibility == VISIBLE, but with other view over it with same state, then the user can't see the icon despite of the visibility status.

Comment: What you could do is get all the possible views that would overlap your X view. You could then get the X view's coordinates and compare it with all other view's cordinates and if they match then check elevation of the matched views whichever view has more elevation is overlapping the other.